# Reclicking in a UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there a way to give an action to a reclick of an UITabBarItem? I want to back to the initial screen of my app when the tab bar item is reclicked. I'm using a UITabBarController with UITabBar and UITabBarItens. My app have a list of views with foward and backward controls. I wish that UITabBarItem act like a home button.

Comment: That wouldn't be an intuitive action for the user.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: it's actually a standard iOS behavior.

Comment: @jtbandes: Really? I have never seen nor used this feature.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: yep. For example try going to the Phone app, contacts tab, then tap a name to drill down, then tap the contacts tab again.

Comment: @jtbandes: So, does it return the user to the root controller or just go back one?

Comment: Its only one controller with different views inside it.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: it goes back to the root.

Comment: My app have a UITabBarController that call UIViewControllers. This controllers handle a list of views controlled with a UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is given to you automatically if you use UINaviationController: when you "reclick" a tab it will pop to the root view controller.

Your other option would be to implement the UITabBarDelegate or UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol and perform an action when the tab is clicked.

Comment: I'm using a UITabBarController with UITabBar and UITabBarItens. My app have a list of views with foward and backward controls. I wish that UITabBarItem act like a home button.

Comment: Consider using UINavigationController inside your tab bar. Otherwise you might have to override some private methods or something to make this work properly.

Comment: @flopes: actually, I think you can do it using delegate methods. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!! The UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol works fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Its default in the UINavigation controller implementation. If you have a UINavigationController and tap an icon in a tab bar, it will pop view controllers until it reaches the root assuming the navigation controller is a child and is one of the tab bar item's controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a UITabBarControllerDelegate

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{

    if (tabBarController.selectedViewController == viewController)
    {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex =0;
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Cheers
nettz

Comment: Thank you for complement @jtbandes answer.